# Restart ArrayList within For-Loop

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, arraylist, while-loop

I'll keep this simple:
I have an ArrayList of names, I have to remove certain words that contain a specific letter, but I am having trouble restarting the for-loop. This is what I got:

```
public static void someRandomFunction(){
    List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello",
                                                     "Everyone",
                                                     "I'm",
                                                     "Struggling",
                                                     "In",
                                                     "Computer",
                                                     "Science"));

    System.out.println("Start of List: " + wordList + "\n"); 
    System.out.println("\nDrop: \"a\""); 
    someRandomFunction(wordList, "a");
    System.out.println("wordList is now: " + wordList);
}

public static List<String> removeIfContains(List<String> strList, String removeIf){

    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>(strList); // creating a copy

    for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++){
        if(tempList.get(i).contains(removeIf))
            tempList.remove(i);
    }

//Return will not work because of incompatible types.
}
```

An example of what the compiled code should be:

> ArrayList [ Hello, Everyone, I'm, Am, Struggling, In, Computer, Science]
>
> Remove words that start with "A":
>
> New ArrayList [Hello, Everyone, I'm, Struggling, In, Computer, Science]
>
> Remove words that start with "I":
>
> New ArrayList [Hello, Everyone, Am, Struggling, Computer, Science]

The problem with my code is that it won't return the wordlist to how it was before as it begins to read the new word it needs to drop.

Comment: If you need to preserve the original state, make a copy of the list before you make changes. `List<String> wordListCopy = new ArrayList<>(wordList)`

Comment: Do you need to do your changes to the same List or you can use a new one ?

Comment: No, so the list is already set up in a particular way. I'm not changing the ArrayList. I just want it to work for each instance in which I have to remove the word that starts with a specific letter.

Comment: Why not create a new list with the words that *don't* stay with the letter and use that?

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to remove each element in an `ArrayList` that starts with a certain letter you can utilize the [`removeIf()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#removeIf-java.util.function.Predicate-) method which:

> Removes all of the elements of this collection that satisfy the given predicate.

```
wrodList.removeIf(e -> e.contains(thisLetter));
```

(Java 8+ required)

It sounds like you want the list to reset after each time you remove elements. To do this you can create a copy `ArrayList` to check against, and then after each time, set it back to the original:

```
List<String> copy = new ArrayList<>(wordList); //Creates a copy of wordList
```

Comment: Instructions are to remove if contains; not starts with. Good approach. Java 8 is required for this approach

Comment: Hey! Thanks! however, wordList.removeIf() isn't applicable for my situation. Also, I have the ArrayList copy, how can I somehow use that to restart the for-Loop?

Comment: @KristyCompany Use the `removeIf()` on the copy

Comment: removeIf () is not working for the program that I'm using. When I compile it, it's unrecognizable.

Comment: You are probably using a lower version than Java 8 @KristyCompany

Comment: I am. Is there a way to solve it without using that method?

Comment: You can use the loop you have in your question, you just have to remove from the copy, not the original

Comment: When I use the copy, it's insufficient because the way the code is set up is to return the original WordList. So when I remove something from the WordListCopy it does nothing to the compiled result.

Comment: @KristyCompany Please clarify what you want to return. If you want to return the modified list, return the copy

Comment: How do I return the copy?

Comment: Replace `wordList` with `wordListCopy` in your return statement

Comment: It won't let me create a return statement because they are incompatible types.

Comment: @KristyCompany How did you return the orignial `List` then? Please post a [MCVE]

Comment: Is there a way that I can show you my example in a private chat? Because it's kind of long and a little complicated.

Comment: private static void wordLetters (ArrayList<String> wordList, String removeLetter)

for (int I = wordList.size () - 1; I > = 0; I --)
{String removeThis = words.get(i);
if (removeThis.startsWith(removeLetter))
{
wordList.remove(removeLetter);
}
}

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you are looking for. I'm not sure if you want a an instance or static method. I believe your issue is that you are not creating a copy. I noted where I was creating a copy. Good luck in CS.. we've all struggled at one point.

```
public static void someRandomFunction(){
    List<String> arrList = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Hello",
                                                         "Everyone",
                                                         "I'm",
                                                         "Struggling",
                                                         "In",
                                                         "Computer",
                                                         "Science"));

    System.out.println(removeIfContains(arrList, "H")); // calling the function and passing the list and what
    System.out.println(removeIfContains(arrList, "I")); // I want to remove from the list
}

public static List<String> removeIfContains(List<String> strList, String removeIf){
    List<String> tempList = new ArrayList<>(strList); // creating a copy

    for(int i = 0; i < tempList.size(); i++){
        if(tempList.get(i).contains(removeIf))
            tempList.remove(i);
    }

    return tempList; // returning the copy
}
```

Comment: Kristy, you want to accept a List<String> not an ArrayList<String>. That's why the return type isn't working.